# Verifying unauthorized modifications to website

Tags: web-services, http, authentication

I made a script that crawls through a domain, and I want it to determine if there were any unauthorized modifications. For static pages I can simply compare to a pre-set hash value, but for dynamic-length pages, what's a good way to check if any significant changes were made?

Sorry if it sounds dumb.

Comment: How do you define a change to a dynamic page? Someone could add a conditional that rarely appears and your crawler would miss it. It's impossible to detect all changes without the source.

Comment: I mean, is there any static information in possibly the header or anywhere that would change upon defacement that I could use to compare between a pre-set value and during subsequent checks

Comment: Not for a dynamically generated page. In fact, an attacker could set up the page so that it serves up the correct version for your crawler and shows the defaced version to everyone else.

Comment: Assuming they don't do that, how would I be able to tell it was defaced without actively viewing it from a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the pages locally, then use `diff` to check the length of the answer. Eg,

```
diff old_version new_version | wc
```

which will give you a summary of the length of the changes.

Comment: Would there be an acceptable range of content length changes like between -500 or +500 characters? Anything lower or higher would indicate defacement?

Comment: That's up to you to decide and depends on your site.